# in a form, select the second table and the first tr

Tags: jquery

In a form, I want to select the second table and the first tr, and I wish to know if there are more than 1 way to do this with the selectors of jQuery. I mean combination of selectors.

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
    <table class="table beauty-table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="beauty-hover">
                    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Nombre">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h4>Crear Campo</h4>
                    <!--<input class="enviar" type="submit" value="Crear">-->
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table id="columnas" class="table beauty-table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>tipo</th>
                <th>longitud</th>
                <th>predeterminado</th>
                <th>indice</th>
                <th>null</th>
                <th>A_I</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="beauty-hover">
                    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Nombre">
                </td>
                <td class="">
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option>Texto</option>
                        <option>Numerico</option>
                        <option>Booleano</option>
                        <option>Porcentaje</option>
                        <option>$</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td class="">
                    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Longitud">
                </td>
                <td class="">
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option>NINGUNO</option>
                        <option>LLAVE FORANEA</option>
                        <option>LLAVE PRIMARIA</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td class="">
                    <label>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox"></input>
                            <i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>
                    </label>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox"></input>
                            <i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox"></input>
                            <i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="crear">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <button id="crearb" class="enviar" type="button" value="Crear">Crear</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First one that pops to mind, **[:eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)**

```
$('form table:eq(1) tr:eq(0)')
```

```js
$('form table:eq(1) tr:eq(0)').css('background', 'green');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="POST">
                <table class="table beauty-table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Nombre</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="beauty-hover"><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Nombre"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><h4>Crear Campo</h4><!--<input class="enviar" type="submit" value="Crear">--></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                </table>
                <table id="columnas" class="table beauty-table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Nombre</th>
                                <th>tipo</th>
                                <th>longitud</th>
                                <th>predeterminado</th>
                                <th>indice</th>
                                <th>null</th>
                                <th>A_I</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="beauty-hover"><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Nombre"></td>
                                <td class=""><select class="form-control">
                                    <option>Texto</option>
                                    <option>Numerico</option>
                                    <option>Booleano</option>
                                    <option>Porcentaje</option>
                                    <option>$</option>
                                </select></td>
                                <td class=""><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Longitud"></td>
                                <td class=""><select class="form-control">
                                    <option>NINGUNO</option>
                                    <option>LLAVE FORANEA</option>
                                    <option>LLAVE PRIMARIA</option>
                                </select></td>
                                <td class=""> <label> <div class="checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox"/> 
                                    
                                    
                                </div></label>
                                </td>
                                <td class=""><div class="checkbox">
                                
                                    <input type="checkbox"></input> 
                                    <i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>
                                    
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class=""><div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox"></input> 
                                    <i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>
                                   
                                    </div> </label>
                                </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

The next one is **[:not()](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)**

```
$('form table:not(:first) tr:first')
```

```js
$('form table:not(:first) tr:first').css('background', 'green');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="POST">
                <table class="table beauty-table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Nombre</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="beauty-hover"><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Nombre"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><h4>Crear Campo</h4><!--<input class="enviar" type="submit" value="Crear">--></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                </table>
                <table id="columnas" class="table beauty-table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Nombre</th>
                                <th>tipo</th>
                                <th>longitud</th>
                                <th>predeterminado</th>
                                <th>indice</th>
                                <th>null</th>
                                <th>A_I</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="beauty-hover"><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Nombre"></td>
                                <td class=""><select class="form-control">
                                    <option>Texto</option>
                                    <option>Numerico</option>
                                    <option>Booleano</option>
                                    <option>Porcentaje</option>
                                    <option>$</option>
                                </select></td>
                                <td class=""><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Longitud"></td>
                                <td class=""><select class="form-control">
                                    <option>NINGUNO</option>
                                    <option>LLAVE FORANEA</option>
                                    <option>LLAVE PRIMARIA</option>
                                </select></td>
                                <td class=""> <label> <div class="checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox"/> 
                                    
                                    
                                </div></label>
                                </td>
                                <td class=""><div class="checkbox">
                                
                                    <input type="checkbox"></input> 
                                    <i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>
                                    
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class=""><div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox"></input> 
                                    <i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>
                                   
                                    </div> </label>
                                </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Finally, **[:last](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)** (works because you have only two tables)

```
$('form table:last tr:first')
```

```js
$('form table:last tr:first').css('background', 'green');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="POST">
                <table class="table beauty-table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Nombre</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="beauty-hover"><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Nombre"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><h4>Crear Campo</h4><!--<input class="enviar" type="submit" value="Crear">--></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                </table>
                <table id="columnas" class="table beauty-table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Nombre</th>
                                <th>tipo</th>
                                <th>longitud</th>
                                <th>predeterminado</th>
                                <th>indice</th>
                                <th>null</th>
                                <th>A_I</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="beauty-hover"><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Nombre"></td>
                                <td class=""><select class="form-control">
                                    <option>Texto</option>
                                    <option>Numerico</option>
                                    <option>Booleano</option>
                                    <option>Porcentaje</option>
                                    <option>$</option>
                                </select></td>
                                <td class=""><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Longitud"></td>
                                <td class=""><select class="form-control">
                                    <option>NINGUNO</option>
                                    <option>LLAVE FORANEA</option>
                                    <option>LLAVE PRIMARIA</option>
                                </select></td>
                                <td class=""> <label> <div class="checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox"/> 
                                    
                                    
                                </div></label>
                                </td>
                                <td class=""><div class="checkbox">
                                
                                    <input type="checkbox"></input> 
                                    <i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>
                                    
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class=""><div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox"></input> 
                                    <i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>
                                   
                                    </div> </label>
                                </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use:

```
var tr = $('form table:eq(1) tr').first(); //OR
var tr = $('form table:eq(1) tr:eq(0)'); //OR
var tr = $('form').find('table').eq(1).find('tr').first();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using various selectors  as follows.

As per your html, you have a `id` for second table to you can use `id` selector to target the second table which is the simplest and fastest.

```
$('#columnas tbody tr:first');
```

Next you can use [:eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector which reduces the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.

```
$('form table:eq(1) tbody tr:first')
```

Next you can use [:nth-child()](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector which selects all elements that are the nth-child of their parent and as per your html it will select the second table.

```
$('form table:nth-child(2) tbody tr:first')
```

Note: `tr:first` will select the first `tr`.